# UNIT TESTING SHOWS ERROR: file or directory not found:

Tags: python, import, module, pytest

Please, i am new to pytesting and i have been trying to run the test code file but it keeps displaying "Error: file or directory not found". i need someone to put me through to know where i made mistake.
Thank you.

[My TEST CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geV4S.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Instead [edit] your question and include code for a [mcve]. Is your IDE not finding your test? Can you run the tests on the command line? Or is your test using a file? IMHO you should keep the filesystem out of your tests, it's too messy.

Answer (score 1):

A file to be tested (test_squarednumber.py) must be identified. Currently, you are running pytest with only the file name, so you can't identify the file.
Here are some ways to resolve the issue:

**[Method 1] Specify the correct path**

Execute the following command

```
pytest <path of the directory containing the file>\test_squarednumber.py
```

**[Method 2] Change current directory**

Move to `My practices` directory using cd command etc.
Execute the following command

```
pytest test_squarednumber.py
```

**[Method 3] Test test_*.py in the current directory**

Execute the following command.
test_*.py in the current directory will be tested.In this case(current directory is NITIDA), test_squarednumber.py is tested.

```
pytest.
```

See below for details on the rules that determine what to test.
https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html
chapter: Conventions for Python test discovery

Comment: I've tried the first and third method but it's still not working, for the second option The test code is already in the "My practices" directory.

Comment: Let's talk about Method2.
In the your image, the current directory is [C:\Users\NITDA]
Therefore, change the current directory using the following command in the terminal.
[cd C:\Users\NITIDA\Desktop\Python(25-10-2022)\My practices]
Then run the following command.
[pytest test_squarednumber.py]

Comment: It worked, i really appreciate. please any suggestions on becoming a better python developer.